# In this R code, trying to make a confusion matrix. I get this error that the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Tags: r, knn, confusion-matrix

So in this code below, I'm trying to make a confusion matrix. The error

> Error in confusionMatrix.default(data = as.factor(knn_df), reference = as.factor(test_price)) :
> the data cannot have more levels than the reference

comes up.

I am trying to make a KNN model for housing prices. The knn_df has 176 levels and the test_price has 109 levels. Is it normal that it is lower and should I match the amount of levels manually, or did I make a mistake when splitting the data?

Below is the full code. model_df consists out of Price, Area, Room, Lat, Lon.

```
model_df <- filter(model_df, model_df$Price < quantile(model_df$Price, 0.98))
model_df <- filter(model_df, model_df$Area < quantile(model_df$Area, 0.98))

model_df[, c("Area", "Room", "Lon", "Lat")] <- scale(model_df[, c("Area", "Room", "Lon", "Lat")])

set.seed(123)
msplit <- runif(nrow(model_df)) < 0.7
train_df <- model_df[msplit, ]
test_df <- model_df[!msplit, ]

train_ind_vars <- train_df[, c("Area", "Room", "Lon", "Lat")]
train_price <- train_df$Price
test_ind_vars <- test_df[, c("Area", "Room", "Lon", "Lat")]
test_price <- test_df$Price

knn_df <- knn(train = as.matrix(train_ind_vars), test = as.matrix(test_ind_vars), cl = train_price , k = 30 )

confusion_matrix <- confusionMatrix(data = as.factor(knn_df), reference = as.factor(test_price))
```

Comment: If that is `dplyr::filter` (and not `stats::filter`), stop using `model_df$` when your filter is on `model_df` originally. `dplyr::filter` encourages using the symbol `Price` by itself, and using `model_df$...` is going to cause problems when it is used further into dplyr pipes.

Comment: The package `conflicted` is super handy for this. Just add `library(conflicted)` at the top of your scripts, and any name space conflicts will be flagged when they arise.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.